# Implementation for decision procedure for the theory of the reals

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving, cvc4

Is there an implementation for the [first-order theory of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories#Rings_and_fields)? I know there exists one technique by Collins based on cylindrical algebraic decomposition but I don't know of any theorem provers that implement it.

Comment: That's a programming specific forum, so you better explain what you try to achieve, because other people might not be familiar with the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision procedures implemented by z3 for various arithmetic domains is listed here: [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-arithmetic](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-arithmetic).